# Publishing android app: This app is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android, google-play

Publishing and Android app I can see the app in the market but I everyone is watching this text

```
This app is incompatible with all of your devices.
```

Here is the permissions and features of my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
```

and from gradle.build

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 21
```

I dont understand why it doesnt show supported phones.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was one of the dependencies imported in gradle.

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8'
```

We replaced with this

```
commons-codec:commons-codec:1.8
```

And the application became available for all the devices.

Comment: What was it about the dependency that caused the incompatibility?

Comment: @sbaar for some reason is not including the dependency 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8' when it builds the application. Then it verifies if android already has it, but it doens't. So it appears that none device is compatible in production while in development is working.

Comment: @agusgambina How did you find out which dependency was not included? Trial end error or is there a way? I probably have the same issue.

Comment: @Episodex sorry for the delay, I don't remember how I'd got there, but there was a way to have a more verbose output, and there I could notice that the library was the problem, it was too big, so I need to specify a smaller library.

Comment: @agusgambina thx for info. I wrote to Google Play support and they found out that I use a permission that is provided by no existing device (surprisingly it was hardware.camera2 which is recommended on Android's page). I removed the dependency because I anyway didn't need it, but switching to hardware.camera would also probably do the trick. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a supports-screens tag in your AndroidManifest.xml ?  If not, try adding this:
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />

Comment: In the market google show me all the screen that are supported, thank you @BlueCoder

Comment: In that case, try this to determine the cause:  [Find out why apps are incompatible with your android device](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/06/find-out-why-apps-are-incompatible-with-your-android-device/)

Comment: thank you, I tryed that but seems is not working anymore, or for some reason is not showing why my phones are not compatible.